# region of integration $X+Y>2$ of a probability

Tags: probability, integration

im not sure why this probability is giving me ∞.
$ e^{-(x+y)} $ for $x>0$ and $y>0$, and you have to find $P(X+Y>2)$ This is what i did:
$$ \int_2^∞ \int_{2-x}^∞ e^{-(x+y)}  \,dy\,dx$$
THANK YOU

Comment: MathJax hint:  To get multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces.  So e^{-(x+y)} gives $e^{-(x+y)}$ instead of $e^-(x+y)$ without the braces

Comment: Without seeing your work, we can't comment on where you went wrong.  The limits on the outer interval should be $0$ to $\infty$ and the inner integral should be over $x$ if the lower limit depends on $y$

Comment: thanks, i corrected the intervals, but still probability is giving me ∞.

Comment: No, the outer integral is from 2 to infinity, not 0 to infinity.  If x and y are non-negative and x+ y> 2, x cannot be less than 2.

Comment: user247327 do you think is a mistake in the problem?, maybe it should say P(X+Y<2)

Comment: @user247327 That's not correct. For instance, if $x=1$ and $y=1.5$.

Comment: Neither should give you an infinite answer.  We have $P(X+Y\lt 2) + P(X+Y) \gt 2=1$  Maybe you dropped a sign when integrating $e^{-x}?$

Comment: kccu: you are right.  Don't know what I was thinking!

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_2^{\infty} \int_{\max(0,2-x)}^{\infty} e^{-(x+y)}  \,dy\,dx$ as you cannot have $y \lt 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw a picture that includes the line $x+y=2$. You will see that the integral needs to be broken up as
$$\int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=2-x}^\infty e^{-(x+y)}\,dy\,dx +\int_{x=2}^\infty \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-(x+y)}\,dy\,dx.$$
If you want to avoid a split integral, first calculate $\Pr(X+Y\le 2)$. We have
$$\Pr(X+Y\le 2)=\int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=0}^{2-x} e^{-(x+y)}\,dy\,dx.$$

We could alternately in each case integrate first with respect to $x$. By symmetry this just means interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The integral should be over the region $x>0$, $y>0$, and $x+y>2$ (equivalently, $y>2-x$). That region is the first quadrant with a small triangle near the origin chopped off. The outer integral should have $0$ to $\infty$ as its limits. You need to split the inner integral into two integrals, one for $0<x<2$, and one for $x \geq 2$. This is because if $0<x<2$, then you have a constraint on what $y$ can be in terms of $x$ (in particular, it must be greater than $2-x$). However, if $x \geq 2$, then $2-x$ is negative (or non-positive), so it should not be the lower limit of the inner integral; instead, $0$ should be the lower limit.

I can expand if you want more explanation.